# NCOVER without NUNIT Test cases

Tags: code-coverage, manual, ncover

I understand NCOVER is an awesome tool to instrument .dll and run Nunit test cases. Is it possible to instrument .dll's and run manual test cases using NCOVER?

If yes how? If not then is there a .NET tool that can provide such a provision?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you can run NCover on manually tested code, just the same as you would for unit tests or other automated code. You don't actually have to run a separate instrumentation step. Instrumentation is done automatically in the background.

In NCover 4 you would simply setup a project that monitors your application, and when it starts up NCover will automatically begin collecting coverage.

Comment: Hey Thanks for that Info, but i am looking at running the .dll (compiled) whithout the ncover executable....

Comment: So what program will load the .dll? You can't a .dll without a host program.